# How to show table if table has row?

Tags: jquery, html

We have thousands of tables in one HTML page. most of them are empty and be hided using display:none.

We want to show only those tables which has rows.
But following code does not work. Jquery is used.

```js
$('.table1').each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('TD')) {
    $(this).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<TABLE BORDER="3" CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="1" class="table1" style="display:none;">
  <CAPTION>pillowsandcushions-au:</CAPTION>
  <TR id="TR_311511608755">
    <TD ALIGN="center">Family 4 Pack Of Bed Pillows, Soft Medium Firm Australian Made Cotton Cover New</TD>
  </TR>


  <TABLE BORDER="3" CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="1" class="table1" style="display:none;">
    <CAPTION>freodarts:</CAPTION>
  </TABLE>

  <TABLE BORDER="3" CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="1" class="table1" style="display:none;">
    <CAPTION>2clickshere:</CAPTION>
  </TABLE>
```

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work? Do you mean the tables do not show?

Comment: Your HTML is _very_ out of date. The attributes are mostly deprecated.

Comment: Yeah, he must be reading some old books. :)

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).find("td")` always returns a jQuery object, even if the selector doesn't find anything, and an object is always truthy. If you want to know if anything matched, get the length.

```js
$('.table1').each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('TD').length > 0) {
    $(this).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<TABLE BORDER="3" CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="1" class="table1" style="display:none;">
  <CAPTION>pillowsandcushions-au:</CAPTION>
  <TR id="TR_311511608755">
    <TD ALIGN="center">Family 4 Pack Of Bed Pillows, Soft Medium Firm Australian Made Cotton Cover New</TD>
  </TR>


  <TABLE BORDER="3" CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="1" class="table1" style="display:none;">
    <CAPTION>freodarts:</CAPTION>
  </TABLE>

  <TABLE BORDER="3" CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="1" class="table1" style="display:none;">
    <CAPTION>2clickshere:</CAPTION>
  </TABLE>
```

Also, instead of a loop, you can use the `:has` selector.

```js
$('.table1:has(td)').show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<TABLE BORDER="3" CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="1" class="table1" style="display:none;">
  <CAPTION>pillowsandcushions-au:</CAPTION>
  <TR id="TR_311511608755">
    <TD ALIGN="center">Family 4 Pack Of Bed Pillows, Soft Medium Firm Australian Made Cotton Cover New</TD>
  </TR>


  <TABLE BORDER="3" CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="1" class="table1" style="display:none;">
    <CAPTION>freodarts:</CAPTION>
  </TABLE>

  <TABLE BORDER="3" CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="1" class="table1" style="display:none;">
    <CAPTION>2clickshere:</CAPTION>
  </TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test is wrong, as it will always result in a truthy value (a jQuery object). You need to change your test to `if ($(this).find('TD').size())`. I've edited your snippet below.

```js
$('.table1').each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('TD').size()) {
    $(this).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<TABLE BORDER="3" CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="1" class="table1" style="display:none;">
  <CAPTION>pillowsandcushions-au:</CAPTION>
  <TR id="TR_311511608755">
    <TD ALIGN="center">Family 4 Pack Of Bed Pillows, Soft Medium Firm Australian Made Cotton Cover New</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>

  <TABLE BORDER="3" CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="1" class="table1" style="display:none;">
    <CAPTION>freodarts:</CAPTION>
  </TABLE>

  <TABLE BORDER="3" CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="1" class="table1" style="display:none;">
    <CAPTION>2clickshere:</CAPTION>
  </TABLE>
```

Comment: `.size()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 3.0. `.length` is the preferred way.